# In firebase, How can I use callback after onDisconnect().remove()?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm using firebase (angularFire)

I want to use callback after `onDisconnect().remove()` fired.

for example, after remove(), I want to code console.log("Hi I'm removed");

How can I do this ?

Can I do this like this ?

```
... .onDisconnect().remove(function(){
console.log("Hi I'm removed");
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onDisconnect` runs on the Firebase servers, when they detect that the connection to the client has been lost. Since the connection has been lost, there is no way to trigger a callback anymore.

I'm guessing that you want to run some code in the client too when it detects the connection to the server has been lost. This is possible, but it's a different piece of code:

```
var connectedRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    // We're connected (or reconnected)
  }
  else {
    // We're disconnected
  }
});
```

See the section in the [Firebase docs on presence management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample).